# Invoke-ASCmd not a cmdlet in Powershell Module sqlserver (version 21.1.18228)

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to do some automation with SQL Server Analysis Services using Powershell.

Research points me to "Invoke-ASCmd" command as the one to use as per this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-ascmd?view=sqlserver-ps#examples

However, even after installing the SqlServer Module, I don't see "Invoke-ASCmd" in the list of commands. I'm assuming this comes default with this module. If I run this command with no parameters, I get the following response:

"Invoke-ASCmd: The term 'Invoke-ASCmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

If I do a Get-Command -module sqlserver I don't see "Invoke-ASCmd" in the list.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you want to make sure that the SQL Server Module is installed and available.
You can do this by using **Get-Module** cmdlet.

`Get-Module SqlServer -ListAvailable`

Once you are sure SQL Server Module is installed you want to import by using **Import-Module** cmdlet as well as specifying version.

`Import-Module SqlServer -Version 21.1.18080`

After that you can use **Get-Command** cmdlet to see if particular module is loaded and has needed commands you trying to use. Like so:

`Get-Command -Module SqlServer`

Comment: Yep, ran those before. For the "... -ListAvailable" command, output was: ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Script     21.1.18228            SqlServer                           Desk      {Add-RoleMember, Add-SqlAvailabilityDat…

Comment: For the "...Get-Command -Module SqlServer", the output did not have the "Invoke-ASCmd" command. I wanted to paste the output, but it said it was too long. Any other ideas?

Comment: @thomassantosh, Have you just installed the module? I am not 100% sure but I think you must reboot the OS upon installing that module.

Comment: I had not rebooted before.... Just did that. No change in status. Going through the Get-Command again, the only "Invoke" commands are Invoke-SqlAssessment, Invoke-Sqlcmd (as cmdlets) and Invoke-SqlNotebook (as a function).

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is still a difference between Windows Powershell and Powershell Core including for the sqlserver module. Quite a few cmdlets have not yet been ported and maybe some will never be. See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7876) for comments from the MSFT team, e.g. from Christian Wade in Jan 2020 and from Matteo-T in Jan 2021.

So if you need the "AS" commands best stick with Windows Powershell if possible.